# Как вывести остальные элементы из таблицы в БД MySql?

Tags: php, mysql

Проблема лишь в том, что выводит последний элемент из таблицы "ingredient", а первый игнорирует, не могу понять как отобразить его на экране в `<Input>`.

У меня есть таблица, которая связана с другой, и когда я вывожу элементы с индексом 1 (у меня две записи с индексом 1, и одна запись с индексом 2), он выбирает последний с индексом 1 и выводит его.

Как вывести первый элемент? Я пытался сделать это методом explode, но так получается, что у обоих записей меняется ключ на 0.

```
<?php $sql = "SELECT * FROM `Ingredient` WHERE id_ingr = '1'";
                        if($result = $conn2->query($sql)){
                            foreach($result as $row ){
                              
                                $ingredient = $row['ingredient'];
                            }
                        }
                       
                        
                    ?>
                    <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox"  name ="checkboxx[]" value="<?php $ingredient?>" id="checkbox1" checked/><label class="label" for="checkbox1"><?php echo $ingredient ;?></label>
```

Answer (score 1):

Так у вам сначала цикл, а потом уже вывод input. Вывод тоже нужно поместить внутрь цикла.

Например, вот так

```php
<?php 
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM `Ingredient` WHERE id_ingr = '1'";
  if($result = $conn2->query($sql)){
    $count = 0; 
    foreach($result as $row ){
      $count++;
      $ingredient = $row['ingredient'];
?>
   <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox"  name ="checkboxx[]" value="<?php echo($ingredient); ?>" id="checkbox<?php echo($count); ?>" checked/><label class="label" for="checkbox<?php echo($count); ?>"><?php echo($ingredient); ?></label>
<?php
    }
  }
?>
```

Comment: Большое спасибо, вы очень помогли